# How to return a javascript object from php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I've been on this for hours already, I've read tons of articles and still cant figure it out.
Here's the deal.

I am working with Chrome extensions and I want to do a call to my server that returns me a js object. I dont want to inject this into the page, but I want to be able to use it within my content script.

NOTE: I cannot use eval() (I have tried though) and I cannot use jsonp

I am using a framework so my headers arent set here, but they set to return application-type application/javascript utf-8;

my php side looks like this:

```
$refererObj = 'var refererObj = {
        myFunc: function () {
           console.log("hello");
        }
    };';
echo $refererObj;
```

my js looks like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            crossDomain: true,
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            }).done(function(data){
                eval(data);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(refererObj);
            });
```

The first console.log gives `["var refererObj = {↵    getProducts: function () {↵…(products);↵              console.log("hello");↵    }↵};"]`

The second gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: refererObj is not defined"

I get the response as a string with the javascript object and everything is all good until I actually want to "convert" the string into a usable code.

Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Comment: That's not JSON, you are sending back a string that contains JS code.

Comment: You CAN use eval, if you [relax CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval). Consider using a smaller hammer though.

Comment: @Xan, I updated my manifest to use:
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

still no luck with eval.

Also, I really would like the smaller hammer ;)

Comment: @plalx, correct, the response is a string with js code. I updated the question.

Comment: Also, you declare `refererObj` as local - to what scope? It's probable it won't survive outside `eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You actually *can* use `eval()` if you [relax the default Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval) with `unsafe-eval`. But it's a big hammer that's best avoided.
2. You can use JSONP, again, if you can serve it off an https server and [add it to `script-src`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) of the Content Security Policy. This is slightly less of a security risk.

I doubt there is any other solution: anything you load off an external server is to be considered tainted and if you find a way to execute it - congrats, you just bypassed CSP in Chrome and should go claim your bug bounty.

Please note that in case of simply JSON data it's all moot, you can just load it with XHR and `JSON.parse` it. But your example contains code.

Comment: unfortunately https is not currently an option for me.
I have tried to relax the csp, yet eval still doesnt work for me.
Could youpossibly give me an example of how I should write it?
I went over the docs and parsing provided by google... but Im still not succeeding.

Comment: Do you really need arbitrary code? You could have a set of commands your extension executes based on data from the server. And if HTTPS is not an option - make sure those commands are **safe**.

Comment: The example is arbitrary, but the code itself will be used in more than just chrome extensions, so I want to make it possible to get the object with functions from a number of devices.
Thats why I only want to tie chrome specific code into chrome and the rest get from my server.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong `dataType`, as the data returned is not valid JSON. Go read the [jQuery `.ajax()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and try `"jsonp"`; I think your original question is answered though.

Comment: Yes the answers here have been very helpful. however the question was how to change the string to usable code. I have tried eval it is not working (I will update the question to represent this)